# MATLAB, interpolation of 3D curve crossing xy plane

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

In Matlab, I have a 3D-curve (array with 3 coordinates) that crosses the xy-plane in a 3 dimensional coordinate system.  The "curve" is just a bunch of x,y,z points and its shape is elliptical that spans across the 3D space and spirals towards the origin. It crosses the xy plane several times and I would like to interpolate the x and y coordinates when the curve intersects the xy plane (i.e. when z=0). How do I do so?

Comment: I'm confused.. Do you mean to say that you have a 3D array (array with 3 coordinates) in which the value at, say, `A(i,j,k)` denotes the value of the function, say, `f(x,y,z)` for `x=i`, `y=j` and `z=k` (hence a 4D curve)? Or do you rather have a 2D array (array with 2 coordinates) with `f(i,j) = A(i,j)` (hence a 3D curve)?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know the function. I simply know that the curve crosses the xy-plane when I plot it using plot3 function. And I want to compute the coordinates at which the curve intersects the xy plane.

Comment: So, you must be giving it as something like 'plot3(X,Y,Z)`, where `X`, `Y` and `Z` are matrices of the same size right?

Comment: Wait.. Since you're using plot3, the "curve" is just a line?

Comment: No, the "curve" is just a bunch of x,y,z points and its shape is elliptical that spans across the 3D space and spirals towards the origin. It crosses the xy plane several times and I would like to interpolate the x and y coordinates when the curve intersects the xy plane (i.e. when z=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have 3 vectors `x`, `y`, and `z` with coordinates,

```
crossidx = find(diff(sign(z)) ~= 0); % z(zcross) and z(zcross+1) have different signs
z1 = z(crossidx);
z2 = z(crossidx+1);
dz = z2 - z1;
alpha = -z1;
beta = z2;
xcross = (beta*x(crossidx) + alpha*x(crossidx+1))./dz;
ycross = (beta*y(crossidx) + alpha*y(crossidx+1))./dz;
zcross = 0;
hold on; plot3(xcross, ycross, zcross, '*');
```

It should work for either positive to negative or negative to positive crossing. I wrote the code assuming only 1 zero crossing, but I think it would also work for any number of crossings.